# Add an answer "index" feature to questions with more than 5 answers?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred

Pursuant to my idea for [Q:We need something novel to bring in the hordes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/609/2381), I think it would be very useful for all questions with many answers (>5, or so) to have an index of answers.

The index line for each answer could be culled from the first line of the post, accompanied by the user signature, and a mini vote-count/checkmark.

For most of the posts on codegolf.SE, this would effectively provide a list of the programming languages used by each answer without the need to add tags to answers (which I imagine would be a database nightmare).

Comment: I really like this suggestion. It's almost simple enough that it could be accomplished with a user script (excepting questions with multiple pages of answers), so I can't imagine that it would be overly tedious to implement.

Comment: This would take input from the team. In the past they have resisted suggestions that would explicitly support high volumes of answers.

Comment: Figured in case anyone winds up here they should probably note that we have a [stack snippet](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5139/31625) that somewhat accomplishes this.

Comment: [Part of We're not a Q&A site. But what should be done about it?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8358/66833)

Comment: I am marking this as [meta-tag:status-deferred] since this is only really needed on a handful of sites like CGCC and Workplace, and so probably won't be implemented.